# Reductive group terminology questions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$
$\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$

I am a beginner in the subject of reductive groups and I am hoping someone might be able to walk me through some basic terminology. This is not homework so any and all remarks, even those not directly related to what I ask, are helpful. In some sense I am asking many questions, so if moderators wish that I ask separate questions, I will of course do so instead. But I view all of these as trivially tied together and I think it will be easy for someone knowledgeable to answer them all rapid-fire.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of arbitrary characteristic. Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $k$. Let $B=TU$ be a fixed Borel subgroup of $G$, where $T$ is a torus and $U$ is the unipotent radical of $B$. Let $X^*(T):=\Hom(T, GL_1)$ be the **group of characters** or the **weight lattice** and $X_*(T):=\Hom(GL_1, T)$ be the **group of cocharacters** or the **coweight lattice**. Now let $\g$ be the Lie algebra of $G$. The **adjoint representation** of $G$ is given by conjugation on $\g$. A **root** is a nontrivial weight of $G$ that occurs in the action of $T$ on $\g$. The choice of $B$ determines a set of **positive roots**. A positive root that is not the sum of two positive roots is called a **simple root**.  If everything I have written so far makes sense, then I am pretty good up until here.

My questions are the following:

1. What is the meaning of a **coroot**? I have been told that there is a pairing between the weight and coweight lattices, and those coweights corresponding to the roots are called coroots. What precisely is this pairing and what is the meaning of "corresponding to?" And what would the coroots for, say, $GL_n$ look like (with the standard choices of $B$ and $T$)?
2. Similar to #2, what is a **positive coroot** and a **simple coroot**? I have some good guesses but I want to be sure.
3. What is a **dominant weight** and a **dominant coweight**? Why would we care about such weight/coweights?
4. Are there only finitely many dominant weights/coweights?
5. Finally, what are the **fundamental weights** and **fundamental coweights**? It seems that these are necessarily dominant, but I am not sure what their precise definition is. Are there only finitely many of these?

Any and all hints or remarks that you feel may clarify the situation are of course welcome.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: I think Jantzen's book Representations of algebraic groups should be able to answer all your questions.

Comment: As for roots, coroots, weights, coweights, and so on, you need to read about root systems, and representations of semisimple Lie algebras. _Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory_ by Humphreys has a good section on these, as do many other good introductory books. I would recommend against @LetGBeTheGraph's suggestion of reading Jantzen's book to start off with: Jantzen more or less takes familiarity with roots systems for granted, and only revises notation and states results proven elsewhere, such as in Bourbaki. After this, the step to reductive groups will not be hard.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that a choice of simple roots can be done without first fixing a set of positive roots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 .  The pairings you are referring to come from the natural bilinear map

$$X^{\ast}(T) \times X_{\ast}(T) \rightarrow \mathbb Z$$
defined as follows: if $\chi$ is a character of $T$, and $\eta$ is a cocharacter of $T$, then $\chi \circ \eta$ is a morphism of linear algebraic groups $\operatorname{GL}_1 \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_1$.  Consequently, there exists an integer $n$ such that $\chi \circ \eta(x) = x^n$.    We then set $\langle \chi, \eta \rangle = n$.  It's a good exercise to work what this is saying for the special case where $T$ is the group of size $n$ diagonal invertible matrices.

Definition of coroot: for each root $\alpha$ of $T$ in $G$, let $T_{\alpha}$ be the connected component of the kernel of $\alpha$.  There is a unique cocharacter $\alpha^{\vee} \in X_{\ast}(T)$ such that (i) $\langle \alpha, \alpha^{\vee} \rangle = 2$ and (ii) $T$ is generated by $T_{\alpha}$ and $\operatorname{Im} T_{\alpha}$.  Each $\alpha^{\vee}$ is the **coroot** attached to the root $\alpha$.

Actually, it is better to work with a pairing of vector spaces than of abelian groups.  The abelian groups $X^{\ast}(T)$ and $X_{\ast}(T)$ are both free of the same rank, so the vector spaces $V^{\ast} = X^{\ast}(T) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$ and $V_{\ast} = X_{\ast}(T) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$ are of the same dimension, and the pairing above induces a nondegenerate pairing

$$V^{\ast} \times V_{\ast} \rightarrow \mathbb Q$$

$$(v,w) \mapsto \langle v, w\rangle.$$

It is useful to think of $X^{\ast}(T)$ being a lattice inside $V^{\ast}$, and likewise for $X_{\ast}(T)$ inside $V_{\ast}$.

It is not difficult to work out the coroots for $\operatorname{GL}_n$.  They are "identical" to the roots.  If you have trouble with this, ask a new question.

2 .  They are what you expect.  Positive (resp. simple) coroots are those corresponding to positive (resp. simple) roots.  The set of simple roots and the set of simple coroots are each linearly independent sets in $X^{\ast}(T)$ (resp. $X_{\ast}(T)$).

3 - 5: The **fundamental weights** are dual to the simple coroots.  That is, if $\alpha_1, ... , \alpha_n$ are the simple roots, then the fundamental weights $\omega_1, ... , \omega_n$ are the unique elements of $V^{\ast}$ such that $\langle \omega_i, \alpha_j^{\vee} \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

Similarly, the **fundamental coweights** $\omega_1^{\vee}, ... , \omega_n^{\vee} \in V_{\ast}$ are dual to the simple roots: $\langle \alpha_i, \omega_j^{\vee} \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

Dominant weights (resp. coweights) are the elements in $V^{\ast}$ (resp. $V_{\ast}$) of the form $a_1 \omega_1 + \cdots + a_n \omega_n$ (resp. $a_1 \omega_1^{\vee} + \cdots + a_n \omega_n^{\vee}$), where $a_i$ are nonnegative integers.  Of course, there are infinitely many of these whenever $T \subsetneq G$.

There are several reasons to care about dominant/fundamental weights and coweights.  An interesting result is that the sum of the fundamental weights $\omega_1 + \cdots + \omega_n$ is equal to *half* the sum of the positive roots.  These give you the modulus character on the nonunimodular topological group $B(\mathbb C)$ (in the Euclidean, not Zariski, topology).

Also, the *positive chamber* $\{ c_1 \omega + \cdots + c_n \omega : \mathbb R \ni c_i \geq 0\}$ shows up in Arthur's modified trace formula.  I don't know too much about this myself, still learning.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. A few follow-up questions. 1. From what you have written, it seems that the simple roots (resp. coroots) form a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $X^*(T)$ (resp. $X_*(T)$). Is this correct? 2. What is the significance of the "2" in the definition of coroot? Naively, it seems any other number could have been chosen for this definition. 3. It seems your final sentence got cut off.

Comment: 1 .  They form a basis of $V^{\ast} = X^{\ast}(T) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$ (not generally of $X^{\ast}(T)$, as you have divisibility) if and only if $G$ has finite center (that is, if $G$ is semisimple).  If the center is infinite, then it has nontrivial characters, a choice of whose extension to $T$ completes the simple roots in comprising a basis of $V^{\ast}$.

2 .  When you study abstract root systems, you'll see why.  The roots of $T$ in $G$, together with the vector subspace of $V^{\ast}$ spanned by them, is a root system.  The coroots form a "dual" root system.

Comment: Also, the coroots describe certain Euclidean reflections on $V^{\ast}$.  For each root $\alpha$, the linear map $s_{\alpha}: V \rightarrow V$ defined by $s_{\alpha}(v) = v - \langle v, \alpha^{\vee} \rangle \alpha$ sends $\alpha$ to $-\alpha$ permutes the rest of the roots among themselves.  The condition $\langle \alpha^{\vee}, \alpha \rangle = 2$ is essential to that.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. This should be more than enough to orient myself so that I can go and learn all this properly now.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the fundamental weights/coweights are not unique unless $G$ is semisimple, or equivalently if $dim V^*$ is the number of simple roots. If $dim V^*$ is larger, there are many choices of fundamental weights $\varpi_i$ such that $\langle \alpha_j^\vee, \varpi_i\rangle = \delta_{ij}$. For example, in the case of $\operatorname{GL}_n$ the fundamental weights are only defined up to multiples of the determinant character.

Comment: Yes good point.  To make these totally unambiguous one should take roots, weights, coroots etc. using the quotient torus $T/Z$.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused. First, this definition of fundamental weights indicates they are only elements of $V^*$, not of $X^*$. I suppose they are only in $X^*$ exclusively when $G$ is semisimple. No issue. But then this means that not all of the dominant characters are in $X^*$. This disturbs me, because the paper I am trying to read implies that this is the case (with no assumption on $G$). Perhaps I should ask: what is the meaning of the "cone of dominant characters" in $X^*$?

Comment: @AnyaVirtanen The dominant cone (sometimes called fundamental chamber, or dominant chamber) is the set of all $\lambda \in X^*$ satisfying $\langle \alpha_i^\vee, \lambda \rangle \geq 0$ for all simple coroots $\alpha_i^\vee$. Also, the fundamental weights are _defined_ when $G$ is semisimple, and lie in $X^*$ when $G$ is _simply connected_. For example $X^*(\operatorname{SL}_n)$ contains all fundamental weights while $X^*(\operatorname{PGL}_n)$ does not, despite both these groups being semisimple.